# Update UILabel according to NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, c, uilabel, nstimer

I have a UILabel that I would like to update as a countdown timer.  Currently I am using an NSTimer to execute a method when the allotted inactivity time has passed.  I found the code for setting up the desired NSTimer from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch).  I'm using the example code posted by Chris Miles in one of the view controllers for the application, and the method is executing properly when the idle time reaches the `kMaxIdleTimeSeconds`.

However I was hoping to take the code example posted by Chris Miles a step further by updating a UILabel in the view controller with the remaining idle time.  Should I use a completely separate NSTimer to do this, or is there a way to update UILabel with idle time remaining with the current NSTimer before logout?

The view controller implementation file for the application looks like the following,

```
#import "ViewControllerCreate.h"
#import "math.h"

@interface ViewControllerHome ()

#define kMaxIdleTimeSeconds 20.0

@implementation ViewControllerHome

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

// 5AUG13 - idle time logout
    [self resetIdleTimer];

    int idleTimerTime_int;

    idleTimerTime_int = (int)roundf(kMaxIdleTimeSeconds);

    _idleTimerTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d secs til",idleTimerTime_int];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setIdleTimerTime:nil];
    // set the idleTimer to nil so the idleTimer doesn't tick away on the welcome screen.
    idleTimer = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Handling idle timeout

- (void)resetIdleTimer {
    if (!idleTimer ) {
        idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kMaxIdleTimeSeconds
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
    }
    else {
        if(fabs([idleTimer.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) < kMaxIdleTimeSeconds-1.0) {
            [idleTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:kMaxIdleTimeSeconds]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)idleTimerExceeded {
    NSLog(@"lets see what happens");
    [idleTimer invalidate];
    [self logout:nil];
    [self resetIdleTimer];
}

// method is fired when user touches screen.
- (UIResponder *)nextResponder {
    [self resetIdleTimer];
    return [super nextResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: I just answered this recently:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17414593/210171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the code you posted at all. Why not start the label with the max idle time, then call the timer's action method once every second, and subtract 1 from the label's text's intValue. When the label's value reaches 0, do what ever you need to do, and invalidate the timer.

Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.label.text = @"1000";
      [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countDown:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)countDown:(NSTimer *) aTimer {
      self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.label.text  intValue] - 1];
      if ([self.label.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
           //do whatever
           [aTimer invalidate];
      }
}
```

Comment: would you care to elaborate on your answer with a code example?

Comment: @Chris, I've updated with a code example.

Comment: @rdelmar thank you very much, the code example was very helpful.

Comment: You really shouldn't use a direct countdown `[self.label.text  intValue] - 1` like this if you care about accuracy. The `NSTimer` will not fire at exact one second intervals, and delays will accumulate.