# AKMetronome countdown, how to publish to main thread from background thread to start recorder?

Tags: swift, multithreading, audiokit

I've been looking into how to implement a Metronome countdown with the AudioKit lib but ran into an issue related to threads and my implementation.

My implementation uses the AudioKit `AKMetronome`, a method to handle the `metronome.start` and the `metronome.callback` handler to start `recording` after a given number of bars are completed.

```
init () {
  metronome.callback = handler
}

func record () {
    self.metronome.start()
}
```

The handler computes the metronome position in time and if the desired number of bars completes  (countdown), the recorder starts.

Unfortunately, running the `.record` of `AKNodeRecorder` in the `.callback handler` of `AKMetronome` causes the warning message:

```
Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
```

For that reason, the call to start recording in the `metronome.callback` handler is passed to the main thread through the GCD API:

```
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                do {
                    try self.recorder.record()
                } catch {
                    print("[ERROR] Oops! Failed to record...")
                }
            }
```

I've used the `.sync` blocking method to resolve the computation immediately as possible since timing is critical in audio applications (the call should be executed in a real-time thread, ideally). Is my understanding that the GCP API `main thread` provides the highest priority, but I'm not certain if that's the best option for a time-sensitive application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the actual question has nothing to do with metronomes or countdowns? What you really want to know is: will using `sync` from a background thread get me onto the main thread faster?

If so: Basically no. This is not what `sync` is for or what it means. The `async`/`sync` difference has absolutely no effect on speed. If you get onto the main thread using `async`, you will get on as soon it is free, so you gain nothing whatever by saying `sync`.

Moreover, if you already arrived into the callback in an `async` background thread, any damage that can be done is already done; your timing is now inexact and there is absolutely nothing you can do about it unless you happen to have a time machine in your pocket.

Comment: Thanks for looking @matt! The context `audio app` is important because of timing, what I take from your answer is that I should not execute the recorder in the metronome `.callback` since that's already executed in a background thread; I'll move the recorder call out of the `.callback` and execute it along the metronome start and use the `Timer`, but read before that `Timer.scheduledTimer` should not be used because it's not reliable for audio applications. Clearly the fact I'm working in a "timing sensitive app" is important, so hope it's ok to keep it there in the topic :)

Comment: Well I don't know if the `.callback` is done in a background thread, but that is what the error message seems to imply, eh.

Comment: Yes, I have assumed the same based in the message.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @matt advice regarding calls inside callbacks, the approach I took change based in a `.scheduledTimer` of `Timer`.

```
func record () {
    metronome.restart()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: self.barLength, repeats: false) { _ in
        self.startRecording()
        print("Timer fired!")
    }
}
```

The `record` is a `handler` that initiates the `AKMetronome`, opted to use `.restart` so that every time's requested starts from the very start.

A property `.barLength` holds the value for the computed length of `the desired countdown`. The `.startRecording` method that is called, is a handler that takes care of AKRecorder `.record` call.

Future reader, have in mind that `Timer` is not meant to be accurate according to ([Accuracy of NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414344/accuracy-of-nstimer)) but
unfortunately, this is the best approach I've tested and I found so far.